# Buscar los factores primos de un vector con x elementos

Tags: pascal

El ejercicio me pide: ingresar una cantidad x de números naturales mayores que uno y mostrar en pantalla la descomposición en factores primos de cada uno, indicar cual de ellos tiene más factores primos ej.:

**72**: **2**-**2**-**2**-**3**-**3**

**50**: **2**-**5**-**5**

```
type
vec=array [0..100] of byte;
var
    n,r:byte;
    v,m: vec;
    
 procedure leevec(var n : byte; var v: vec);
 var
 i: byte ;
 begin
  write('ingre la cantidad de elementos ');
  readln(n);
   for i:=1 to n do
    begin
      write(i,': ');
      readln(v[i]);
    end; 
 end;

procedure factorprimo(n: byte; var r : byte ;v: vec; var t: vec);
var
i,d:byte;

begin
 for i :=1 to n do
 r:=1;
  while v[i] > 1 do 
  begin
   d:=2;
   while (v[i] mod d <> 0) do
   d:=d+1; // son los factores primos 
   t[r]:=d; 
   r:=r+1; // contador
   v[i]:=v[i] div d;
   
  end;
    end;

    procedure escritura(k:byte; a:vec);
var
i:byte;
    begin
        for i:=1 to k do
            begin
                write(a[i],' ');
                
            end;
        writeln;
    end;
begin
   leevec(n,v);
   factorprimo(n,r,v,m);
   escritura(r-1,v);
end.
```

Esto es lo que pude hacer pero como resultado me sale los factores primos del último elemento del vector y todavía no pude hacer el conteo de quien tiene mas FP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido a StackOverlow en español.

***La primera recomendación*** que te daría el leer tu programa es que utilices variables (al igual que has hecho con los métodos) con nombres descriptivos. `n, r, v, t, d,...` no explican gran cosa y pueden llevar a confusión.

Eso me lleva al primer problema (que tiene que ver con esto).
Haces una llamada al final al método:

```
escritura(r-1,v);
```

Donde el segundo parámetro es el vector a escribir. Le pasas como parámetro una `v` (que es el vector de entrada) y efectívamente el programa está escribiendo los valores del vector de entrada.

Al una entrada como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con 2 valores, `55 y 66` los está devolviendo en la salida (el índice no acaba de funcionar)

***La segunda recomendación***, es que intentes dividir el problema en partes más pequeñas que te sea más fácil programar y comprobar.

Por ejemplo, en el método `factorprimo`, intentas generar los factores de todos los números de entrada (el vector `v`). Lo más lógico sería hacer un procedimiento que calculara **los factores de un sólo número** y hacer luego la llamada con un bucle tantes veces como lo necesites.

Debido a esto llega tu segundo problema. Este procedimiento `factorprimo`, está utilizando el mismo vector de salida para los factores de todos los números. Por eso, sólo almacena los factores del último.
Digamos que calculas los factores de `v[1]` y los almacenas en el `vector t`, y para `v[2]` vuelves a almacenarlo en el `vector t` (machacando los primeros).

Puedes modificar tu mensaje inicial, así que yo intentaría revisar estas cosas y cambiar el código para poder seguir revisando.

Comment: hola muchas gracias por la respuesta. te hago una consulta vos sabes como puedo hacer para qe me almacene los valores de v[1] y v[2] sin que el vector t me borre los resultados anteriores? y el llamado ers este escritura(r-1,m); pero lo copie mal al subirlo por aca.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no vas mal encaminado, mi primera recomendación es utilizar identificadores descriptivos, tanto en los nombres de tipos y variables, como en funciones, procedimientos; en fin, en todo.

Luego, mantener un estándar, en la definición del tipo `Vec` el arreglo va de 0 a 255, y en la rutina que lo lee, comienzas pidiendo en índice 1. Esto, si bien no provoca un fallo, si que crea confusión. Por regla general, en Pascal, los índices de los arreglos estáticos están basados en 1. Si no tienes un buen motivo para hacerlo diferente, ceñirte a esa convención mantendrá la consistencia en tu código.

Juntando estas dos cosas en código, nos iríamos quedando con algo como esto:

```
type
  Vector = array [1..255] of Byte;

procedure LeerVector(var N:Byte; var V: Vector);
...

function EncontrarFactores(Numero: Byte): Byte;
...
```

Luego, quizás por ir muy rápido y tratar de resolver todo el problema a la vez, diría que estás mezclando las ideas. Considero recomendable crear una función que encuentre y cuente los factores de un solo número, y luego tirar de ella para poder responder el problema planteado.

Si lo piensas, ya teniendo esta función, lo que haría falta es ir recorriendo el vector, averiguando el número de factores que tiene cada número y, en cada paso de la iteración, ir viendo si ese es mayor al máximo registrado hasta entonces. Si lo es, registrar ese valor como máximo, recordar el número asociado a él, y así hasta llegar al final del arreglo.

Para entonces, tendremos en memoria el número y la cantidad de factores que corresponden al que más tiene, ya sería cosa solo de imprimirlo.

Haciendo que la función `EncontrarFactores` vaya imprimiendo los factores de cada número y nos devuelva la cuenta de ellos, el programa principal podría lucir algo como esto:

```
var
  N: Byte;
  Entrada: Vector;
  I: Byte;
  MaxFactores: Byte;
  NumeroConMaxFactores: Byte;
  Factores: Byte;
begin
  LeerVector(N, Entrada);
  Writeln;
  Writeln('Busqueda de factores');
  Writeln;
  MaxFactores := 0;
  for I := 1 to N do
  begin
    Factores := EncontrarFactores(Entrada[I]);
    if Factores > MaxFactores then
    begin
      MaxFactores := Factores;
      NumeroConMaxFactores := Entrada[I];
    end;
  end;
  Writeln;
  Writeln('El número que más factores tiene es ', NumeroConMaxFactores, ' con ', MaxFactores, '.');
  Writeln;
  Readln;
end.
```

Lo cual produciría una salida como esta (en mi corrida de prueba):

```
Ingrese la cantidad de elementos: 5
1: 72
2: 50
3: 64
4: 27
5: 23

Busqueda de factores

72: 2,2,2,3,3 (5 factores)
50: 2,5,5 (3 factores)
64: 2,2,2,2,2,2 (6 factores)
27: 3,3,3 (3 factores)
23: 23 (1 factores)

El número que más factores tiene es 64 con 6.
```